# How to parse the multi-list

Tags: python-3.x, list

When made a call like allorders = getallorders()

it returned a list like below

```
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "order_id": “123", 
      "status": "REJECTED",
      "validity": "DAY", 
    }, 
    {
      "order_id": “343”, 
      "status": "REJECTED",
      "validity": "DAY",   
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I iterate through this list and take each order id and corresponding status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this for loop, you can iterate through your json answer allorders and get the desired keys and their value

```
for order in allorders['orders']:
    print('id: ', order['order_id'])
    print('status: ', order['status'])
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.